# Bootstrap Combobox breaking CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

I've got an odd CSS issue when using Bootstrap and bootstrap-combobox JS.

The desired result is to have an option working as expected, within a table. However when the dropdown is selected, lines break and the dropdown doesn't display correctly.

I've tried using a stock Bootstrap CSS file and still can't get it to display properly. Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Dan.

As expected https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqZZf.jpg

As result https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhkUi.jpg

CSS:

```
<div class="row">
<h1>Inline Form</h1>
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select a State</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<select class="combobox form-control" name="inline">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select a State</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should post a working example of your problem.

Comment: Or at least your live page address, if any, so we can inspect it.

Comment: FYI you've got an extra </div> at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I neglected to state that the combobox was being used in a bootstrap modal. The solution was to remove `tabindex="-1"` from the modal div.

Dan.